# Grid-lines on Richtextbox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm wondering whether you can have lines separating each line in a `RichTextBox`, just like you would have on a normal piece of paper. I've been searching around with no luck and would appreciate it if anyone knew how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: WHy do you want to use a RichTextBox for this?

Comment: If your font size is always the same, you could just use some kind of background image or drawing.

Comment: @eddie_cat If there are any other alternative controls, I would gladly appreciate your ideas.

Comment: @Blorgbeard That might work, but, I would have to make the image work in different resolutions etc. But thank you for your idea, I will take this in consideration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <RichTextBox TextBlock.LineHeight="20" TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" Padding="20,10,20,20">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
    <RichTextBox.Background>
        <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="None" Viewport="0,0,20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Opacity="0.1">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="RoyalBlue" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="20,0"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </RichTextBox.Background>
</RichTextBox>
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best idea I came up with is having a `RichTextBox` with a transparent background inside a grid with visible gridlines:

[image]

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" ShowGridLines="True" Height="50" Width="100">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RichTextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="rtb" Height="50" Width="100" Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
```